# How to calculate the logarithmic mean temperature difference of a jacketed vessel?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, heat-transfer, chemical-engineering, pressure-vessel

I'm a bit confused on how to calculate the $ \Delta T_{LM}$ of a jacketed isothermal CSTR. Because the formula for the logarithmic mean temperature difference is:

$$ \Delta T_{LM} = \frac{\Delta T_{reactor-bulk}-\Delta T_{jacket}}{ln(\frac{\Delta T_{reactor-bulk}}{\Delta T_{jacket}})} $$
But in an isothermal reactor, the assumption would be $\Delta T_{reactor-bulk}=0$.

So how to go on from there?

Thanks for your time

Comment: Will that 0 be Kelvin, Fahrenheit or Celcius?

Comment: Lets say we are using SI units, so Kelvin. But I'm guessing you are referring to the change in temperature of the bulk of the reactor, which since it's isothermal is 0. So the units wouldn't really matter much there